# Finding a College of Lore "local group" as an outsider in the city

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, background

I am playing a newly Level3-Bard with the College of Lore. In her backstory she encountered the criminal group The Nine Swords in Westgate, who are protected from high up and her goal is to bring them to justice.

The PHB describes the College of Lore as

> The college’s members gather in libraries and sometimes in actual colleges, complete with classrooms and dormitories, to share their lore with one another. They also meet at festivals or affairs of state, where they can expose corruption, unravel lies, and poke fun at self- important figures of authority.

We will start our next session in Baldur's Gate, and with respect to [How to explain Bard getting College education suddenly?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124355/how-to-explain-bard-getting-college-education-suddenly), I am wondering where she might find these other bards of her college.

Wandering around the docks and library, asking if someone saw another person singing very motivationally or knows of The Nine Swords seems a bit random and helpless. A mentor who taught her the first spells would certainly also tell her about where to find others or contact them, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two levels at which one can answer this, the in-game and the out-of-game.

In the game fiction, yes, you go "look for leads." This is the part of the game where you, in conjunction with the GM, use a combination of deduction and imagination, since all the real-life kind of details aren't fleshed out in the lore.  It's like finding other gamers before the Internet.

### In Game Fiction

#### Deduction

Where might bards hang out in Baldur's Gate? Learn about the setting, ask yourself. "Well, there's a temple to Oghma, the priest there certainly might know.  How about instrument makers and their shops; there can't be that many and they'll know plenty of bards (if not are one themselves)?" Then yes, you go try those, and the GM will decide what happens. Leave a flyer up at a local live music venue, and so on.

#### Imagination

Until The Complete Book Of College Of Lore Bards In The Realms comes out, details are scarce, and while in the 2e/3e days you could probably have counted on that happening in a  year or two, in the 5e world they're not exactly all about publishing any more.  So here's where you, in conjunction with the DM, flesh out those little details.

"Hmm, I think bards of the college of lore would tend to put a little book sigil in specifically friendly places, shops they own, inns where they gather...  Can I look for those?  Also as I wander around I hum the Lore College fight song to see if anyone tweaks to me." Like wearing your shirt with a big ampersand on it out to the mall and getting knowing nods from other geeks.

### Out Of Fiction

You have skills, roll them. The old "gather information" skill is really just a Charisma check in 5e, and one would assume you have a decent Charisma being a bard. At some point you can fall back on your bard's assumed knowledge of their own college and ask the GM if you can roll for it.

Obviously if I were the GM I'd make you do one of the in game fiction things to merit a check, but different tables have different standards.

Comment: *It's like finding other gamers before the Internet* nice analogy.